# There is a function $f$ such that $f \in L^{p}$ and $f \notin L^{q}$ for $p,q \geq 1$ and $p\neq q$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

**Problem:** For $\displaystyle{p \geqslant 1}$,
consider
\begin{align*}
    f ( x ) = \frac{1}{ \displaystyle{ x^{ \frac{1}{p} } \big( \log^{2}{x} + 1 \big) } }
    \qquad
    \text{for all } x \in ( 0 , \infty).
\end{align*}
Show that:
\begin{align*}
    f \in L^{p} \big( ( 0 , \infty ) , m \big)
    \qquad
    \text{and}
    \qquad
    f \notin L^{q} \big( ( 0 , \infty ) , m \big)
    \text{ for all } q \neq p \text{ and } q \geqslant 1.
\end{align*}

***Solution for that $f\in L^{p}$:*** Firstly, we check that:
\begin{align*}
    || f ||_{p}^{p}
    =
    \int\limits_{(0, \infty)} | f ( x ) |^{p} d m ( x )
    =
    \int\limits_{(0, \infty)} \left| \frac{1}{x^{ \frac{1}{p} } ( \log^{2}{x} + 1 ) } \right|^{p} d m ( x )
    =
    \underbrace{ \int\limits_{(0, \infty)} \frac{1}{x ( \log^{2}{x} + 1 )^{p} } d m ( x ) }_{\text{Lebesgue-Integral}}
    =
    \underbrace{ \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x ( \log^{2}{x} + 1 )^{p} } d x }_{\text{Riemann-Integral}}
    =
    \\
    =
    \int\limits_{- \infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{( y^{2} + 1 )^{p}} d y
    \quad
    \Big( \text{we set }
    y = \log{x} \Big)
    \quad
    \leqslant
    \int\limits_{- \infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{y^{2} + 1} d y
    =
    \Big[ \arctan{y} \Big]_{y \to -\infty}^{y \to \infty}
    =
    \pi < \infty
    \Longrightarrow
    f \in L^{p} \big( ( 0 , \infty ) , m \big).
\end{align*}

***My attempt to show that $f \notin L^{q}$:*** Secondly, we have the integral
\begin{align*}
    || f ||_{p}^{q}
    =
    \int\limits_{(0, \infty)} | f ( x ) |^{q} d m ( x )
    =
    \int\limits_{(0, \infty)} \left| \frac{1}{x^{ \frac{1}{p} } ( \log^{2}{x} + 1 ) } \right|^{q} d m ( x )
    =
    \int\limits_{(0, \infty)} \left| \frac{1}{x^{ \frac{1}{p} } ( \log^{2}{x} + 1 ) } \right|^{q} d m ( x )
    =
    \\
    =
    \underbrace{ \int\limits_{(0, \infty)} \frac{1}{x^{ \frac{q}{p} } ( \log^{2}{x} + 1 )^{q} } d m ( x ) }_{\text{Lebesgue-Integral}}
    =
    \underbrace{ \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^{ \frac{q}{p} } ( \log^{2}{x} + 1 )^{q} } d x }_{\text{Riemann-Integral}}
\end{align*}

I was thinking to use the following:
Let a decreasing function $\displaystyle{g : ( 0 , \infty ) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}}$. Then:
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^{n} g ( 2^{n} ) < \infty
\Longleftrightarrow
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} g ( n ) < \infty
\Longleftrightarrow
\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} g ( x ) d x < \infty.
\end{align*}

Since $f$ is decreasing function, it is enough to check the following:
\begin{align*}
    \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{ ( 2^{x} )^{ \frac{q}{p} } ( \log^{2}{2^x} + 1 )^{q} } d x 
    =
    \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{ ( 2^{x} )^{ \frac{q}{p} } ( x^{2} \log^{2}{2} + 1 )^{q} } d x
\end{align*}

*My issue is that: I cannot show $f \notin L^{q}$.
Can you help me? If I have somewhere a mistake please correct me.*

Comment: If $q<p$, use that $\log(x) \leq C_\varepsilon x^\varepsilon$ to get a lower bound on you integrand of the form $x^{-q/p-\varepsilon}$, which is not integrable for $\varepsilon>0$ small enough. For $q>p$ use a similar trick, but this time for $x$ close to the origin.

Comment: If $\displaystyle{q < p}$, then
\begin{align*}
    \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^{ \frac{q}{p} } ( \log^{2}{x} + 1 )^{q} } d x
    \geqslant
    \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^{ \frac{q}{p} } ( C_{\epsilon} x^{2 \epsilon} + 1 )^{q} } d x
    \approx
    \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^{ \frac{q}{p} + \epsilon }} d x
    \xrightarrow[\frac{q}{p}<1]{\epsilon \to 0^{+}} \infty.
\end{align*}

But for the other case $q>p$, what can we do?

Comment: You want to truncate the integral at $1$ (the bound is not valid all the way down to the origin). If $q>p$ we use that $\ln(x)\leq C_\varepsilon x^{-\varepsilon}$ for $0<x\leq 1$.